# How to use bootstrap-datepicker on Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

I am trying to use **bootstrap-datepicker on bootstrap modal**; I have render HTML by **Razor Code** `@Html.TextBoxFor()`.

But Datepicker does not show.

Please help me.

Comment: provide you html and other snippet.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, read these links to improve your question: [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) | [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) | [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Add your script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And set your textbox

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.xxx, new {@class = "form-control datepicker" , @id = "datepicker" })
```